# Android AudioRecord troubles

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

---

```
private static final int SampleRate = 8000; 
private static final int Channels = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int Encoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private void startRecording(){
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SampleRate, Channels,  AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
       if (bufferSize > 0) {
            recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SampleRate, Channels, Encoding, BufferElements2Rec*BytesPerElement);
            recorder.startRecording();
            isRecording = true;
            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    writeAudioDataToFile();
                }
            },"AudioRecorder Thread");
            recordingThread.start();
       }
}
```

This works on device emulator, i have any problems there but in a real phone does not work.  i'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an unitialized AudioRecord.
```

I put in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Comment: Look in your LogCat, do you see the line `"Error code ... when initializing native AudioRecord object."` there?

Comment: yes, "Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object."

Comment: That means your recorder cannot initialize correctly. Try Melquiades's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) for AudioRecord constructor says,

> you should call getState() immediately after construction to confirm
>   that the object is usable.

Possible states are:

**STATE_INITIALIZED**

**STATE_UNINITIALIZED**

In your case, **recorder** is not initialized properly, hence you're getting IllegarArgumentException when calling startRecording().

One of the reasons might be your SampleRate, which is 8000. According to the documentation, 44100Hz is the only rate guaranteed to work on all devices, so please try with this rate first (also, documentation doesn't explicitly state 8000HZ as valid rate).

In your code then, change SampleRate to 44100 and check object state, eg.:

```
private static final int SampleRate = 44100;
```

and later:

```
recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SampleRate, Channels, Encoding, BufferElements2Rec*BytesPerElement);

if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;
    //rest of the code
}
else {
    //not initialized properly
}
```

Comment: I did that but i still having `"Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object."` and `if(recorder.getStatet...)()`  is never called, i mean recorder.getState() is always `AudioRecord.State_Unitialized`

Comment: Check if other parameters for AudioRecord constructor are valid.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (I had the same problem on Android 6 and not on 5) when You first start an app You need to go to Settings>Apps>Yourapp>Permissions and let the app use microphone, after I turned it on, error disappeared.

Better practice is to check for the sdk number on start like this and ask user for permission right inside your app to prevent errors (replace PUT_YOUR_PERMISSION_HERE with the permission You need)  -

```
//check for permission
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M  &&     checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.PUT_YOUR_PERMISSION_HERE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.PUT_YOUR_PERMISSION_HERE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PUT_YOUR_PERMISSION_HERE);

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PUT_YOUR_PERMISSION_HERE is an
                    // app-defined int constant

                    return;
                }
```